# Remove PointLight in ThreeJS Model Loader

Tags: three.js

I am trying to remove the point light (or preferrably any light source), but I am new to ThreeJS... I tried `babylonScene.remove(object);` but I get an error that "cannot call traverse on undefined" or something to that affect. Happy to post the error if that is the suggested approach.

The code below is taken from the ThreeJS example code with the additional removal code.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_babylon.html

```
  var loader = new THREE.BabylonLoader( manager );
    loader.load( data.src, function ( babylonScene ) {
        babylonScene.traverse( function ( object ) {
            if ( object instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                object.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
                    color: Math.random() * 0xffffff
                });
            }
    else if(object instanceof THREE.PointLight){
      console.log("Removing PointLight");
      object.remove();
    }
   });
   ...
    }, onProgress, onError );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best idea would be to set the light intensity at 0, this means you won't see it anymore:

```
var loader = new THREE.BabylonLoader( manager );
loader.load( data.src, function ( babylonScene ) {
    babylonScene.traverse( function ( object ) {
        if ( object instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
            object.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
                color: Math.random() * 0xffffff
            });
        }
else if(object instanceof THREE.PointLight){
  console.log("Removing PointLight");
  object.intensity = 0
}
});
...
}, onProgress, onError );
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I will try this when I get a chance. Thanks. I will up-vote for now and mark correct if I see that it works.